# Disable window maximize/minimize

Tags: c++, window, winapi, maximize

How do I disable the maximizing and/or minimizing capability of a window with the Windows API? The maximize/minimize boxes need to be greyed out and disabled, and double clicking the title bar, dragging to the top of the screen, etc needs to not work also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call SetWindowLong/SetWindowLongPtr to modify a window's styles.

For furthur detail, please refer to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633591%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644898%28VS.85%29.aspx

Then, what do u mean about 'draging to the top of the screen'?

Comment: On Windows 7, you can maximize a window by dragging it to the top of the screen.

Comment: I have tried SetWindowLong but I cannot figure out the correct values to use. Can you give just a little more help?

Comment: Nevermind, found it. You use the current style (via GetWindowLong) and ^= with WS_MAXIMIZEBOX or WS_MINIMIZEBOX to toggle one or the other.